# rake undefined exitstatus in nil:Nilclass

Tags: ruby, rake

I am trying to run rake on a new machine (original machine works fine) . . after running my this i get an error saying . .

*rake aborted 
undefined method exitstatus for nil:nilClass*

any suggestions for how i could see whats going on here?

Comment: Could you try launching rake with --trace and paste the trace to us so that we can actually help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out . . stupid mistake . . i was running from command prompt.. not VS command prompt so it didn't recognize msbuild task

Answer (score 1):

Start with rake --trace